# In Windows 7, How to query times, when the computer was locked?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security

Is there a way to get a list of the following times:

- whenever windows is locked (using windows+l combo)
- whenever windows is unlocked

  in the past week?

I've tried poking in the event log, to no avail.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[**Event ID 4800**](http://eventopedia.cloudapp.net/default.aspx?LogType=Windows+Event+Log&LogName=Security&OSVersion=6&Category=Logon%2fLogoff&Source=Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing&TaskCategory=Other+Logon%2fLogoff+Events&EventID=4800&action=go) should correspond to **The workstation was locked**, and similarly [**Event ID 4801**](http://eventopedia.cloudapp.net/default.aspx?LogType=Windows+Event+Log&LogName=Security&OSVersion=6&Category=Logon%2fLogoff&Source=Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing&TaskCategory=Other+Logon%2fLogoff+Events&EventID=4801&action=go) should correspond to **The workstation was unlocked**.

If you don't see them in the Event Viewer, for recording future events try opening the Local Group Policy Editor (`Start / Run / gpedit.msc`), navigating to:

Computer Configuration / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Advanced Audit Policy Configuration / System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object / Logon/Logoff / Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events

and enabling the checkboxes for **Success** and **Failure**:

[image: 1]

Comment: It's a little odd that, in the Explain tab the event Ids are not shown, as I'm sure that this information would be helpful when auditing the logs.

Comment: Who the hell thought something like this shouldn't be logged by default?!

Comment: For those of you running Windows Home (no Group Policy), run this command in an Admin shell: `auditpol /set /category:"Logon/Logoff" /success:enable /failure:enable` [(Source)](/a/1059881)

Answer (score 1):

I found events corresponding to locking and unlocking in my Windows 7 Security Event log

```
4634 Logoff with (WinKey +L)
4624 and 4672 unlocking.
```

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 10 and active directory, selecting an event ID and username in the filter did not work, but using the following in XML does work:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
      *[
        System[(EventID=4648)]
        and
        EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']='PUT_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE']
       ]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```