# How can I make Windows XP automatically logoff 2 hours after logging in?

Tags: windows-xp, login, scheduled-tasks, logoff

I have a Windows XP netbook and it is protected with a password. I want to be able to control the time other people spend on the computer, so whenever anyone logs in I want the computer to automatically log off after two hours.

Answer (score 1):

How about executing logon script (help: [To assign user logon scripts](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/gptext_assignlogonscripts.mspx?mfr=true)) with following code:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 7200 -w 1000
shutdown /l /f
```

This script will wait 7200 seconds (2 hours) and then force to log off.

Comment: I think this is the most useful thing to do because XP task schedules can't have a delay before they run so a "helper program" or script will have to do. This answer will cause a command prompt window to be on screen for 2hrs that can be closed by the user - thus circumventing the logoff script's process - but due to XP's lack of features there's nothing much more you can do... Windows 7, howevere, DOES have the ability to delay the task start.

Comment: In Windows Vista, there are lock / unlock events, which can be used to run the script without command prompt window: [In Windows 7, How to query times, when the computer was locked?](http://superuser.com/questions/528884/in-windows-7-how-to-query-times-when-the-computer-was-locked). I don't have Windows XP, to check if there are similar events available.

Comment: That, again, is a little more advanced for XP (I think?!)... and even then, it would be no different to the script you've written... a "logon" event would still need to have a script run for 2hrs... a "logoff" event would be useless because the user will be logged off lol...

Comment: You can create **Start a program** action, while creating task in Task Scheduler (`Win + R` > `taskschd.msc`)