# Windows 8.1 randomly enters the lock screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, lock-screen

I have a Windows 8.1 desktop machine which, as the title says, randomly enters in the lock screen.

The lock outs are not periodic and happen even when the user is working the computer.

My first thought was that the keyboard/mouse was faulty and would send random keystrokes to the OS (Win+L), but the problem persisted even with a different keyboard.

I have a table with the time of day when this occurred and matched against the event logs and there seems to be no pattern there.

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you done a virus sweep? Is someone using remote desktop to connect to your machine?

Comment: Virus sweep didn't solve it. I don't have physical access to that machine. The only person with remote access to that machine is me. Moreover, the lock outs are very frequent and very fast (something like 20 times per 8-hours working day).

Comment: Are you physically sat at the machine when they occur?

Comment: This [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/528884/in-windows-7-how-to-query-times-when-the-computer-was-locked) might help understand how they are occurring.